Comparing two files in C - I don't get it why it works
I wrote a code that compares two files. And it worked. I don't understand why.
int cmp_f(char *filename1, char *filename2)
{
    int c1, c2;
    FILE *file1 = NULL;
    FILE *file2 = NULL;

    file1 = fopen(filename1, "r");
    file2 = fopen(filename2, "r");

    if (file1 == NULL || file2 == NULL) {
        printf("Error occured while reading files.\n");
        fclose(file1);
        fclose(file2);
        return -1;
    }

    while ((c1 = fgetc(file1)) != EOF) {
        c2 = fgetc(file2);
        if (c1 != c2) {
            fclose(file1);
            fclose(file2);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    fclose(file1);
    fclose(file2);
    return 1;
}

I tried to iterate characters one by one. First I took one character from file1, and then took a character from file2 which is nested in while loop.
foo@linux:~$ cat file1.txt
This is txt file.
foo@linux:~$ cat file2.txt
This is txt file.!!!

And this two file for example, I thought when 'c1' variable reaches EOF, fgetc(file2) function seems to be not executed. So, if file2 has same character but has additional character, I thought it will return 1 instead of 0.
But when I execute this function, it returns 0.
This code is from main function.
    result = cmp_f(filename1, filename2);
    
    if (result == 1) {
        printf("Same!\n");
    } else if (result == 0) {
        printf("Different!\n");
    }

I tried all cases like file1 has more additional character or completely different and so on.
I want to know why it works.

When you reach the end of the first file, you will not read the second file or check the comparison. Instead the loop just ends and you close the files and return 1. I recommend an infinite loop (e.g. for (;;) or while (true)), and inside read both files. Then if either one is EOF then break the loop. After the loop check if one but not the other file have reached the EOF.

@Someprogrammerdude If it returns 1 then it didnt work. I think OP is saying it correctly identified that the files are different.

"But when I execute this function, it works." When I put your code in a C file, compile and run it, it tells me the files are same. For me that doesn't qualify as "it works".

With your changed statement "But when I execute this function, it returns 0." that is not true for me. Did you run your program in a debugger? Did you really use the program with the 2 files you think, you use?

My apology for writing vague. it returns 1 instead of 0. I edited.

Still wrong. Your question states it returns 0 instead of expected 1.

Sorry for that. I was little confusing. I expected to return 1 but it returned 0.

To refine on my first comment, you could do it with an infinite loop as described in that, and read both files. Then when c1 and c2 are different, no matter if any of them is EOF or not, then break the loop. After the loop you close the files and return the result of c1 != c2.

Aside: the code won't work if one or both of the files could not be opened, because you try to close files that have not been opened.

Maybe you should make a complete compilable example. The obvious answer is the c1 != c2 some point. Maybe you should add a print statement and see what c1 and c2 are.

You could change the while loop to a do { } while loop: do { c1 = fgetc(file1); c2 = fgetc(file2); ... } while (c1 != EOF);.

file1 ends with ..."ile.\n"; file2 ends with ..."ile.!!!\n"; and, of course, '\n' != '!'

Thanks for all your advice. I tried debugger gdb. When getting in to if (c1 != c2) part, c1 has value of 10 (decimal) and c2 has 33. I looked up ASCII table and it says 10 is [LINE FEED] and 33 is '!'. Is [LINE FEED] mean EOF? then why nested code executed?

@pmg Ohh now I get it. So much thanks! Now I can sleep.

Yeah ... '\n' is the 10 you saw in debugger, '!' is the 33. Good night! BTW: EOF is not a character; its int value is negative (usually -1) whereas all valid characters (possibly after conversion from the innards of fgetc()) have a positive value

You also need to take care of the case where one file is larger, but is the same up that point. The files must be the same size to be equal.

"why it works" It doesn't. There are many errors. Here's one: you cannot fclose a null pointer, so the program is likely to crash whenever it cannot open one or both files.

Thanks for all of you guys! I understood there's so many things to fix. Really appreciated. Have a great day.

@WeatherVane Re "check size first": Interesting idea; fseek() (the standard way) may be pretty fast and likely pays for large files. In principle though, proper byte-by-byte comparison takes care of that implicitly, by encountering EOF != .

One remark: A better name for your function would be are_files_equal() because it returns, effectively, a boolean; such functions are best named "is..." or "has..." etc., suggesting a binary answer. True compare functions  (e.g. strcmp), by contrast, often return -1, 0  or 1 depending on either side being larger or both being equal (the 0 case), making them suitable as predicates in sort algorithms. Of course it would be easy to enhance your function's functionality to do that, and a binary are_functions_equal() could be a trivial wrapper around that.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica you are probbaly right. In my own implementation I use a larger buffer with fread() and memcmp().

The code:
while ((c1 = fgetc(file1)) != EOF) {
    c2 = fgetc(file2);
    if (c1 != c2) {
        // close...
        return 0;
    }
}
// close...
return 1;

is wrong. When it reads EOF in the first file, it ends unconditionally returning 1 (files are the same). It does not correctly tackles the case where both files are equals (ie when c1 and c2 both equals to EOF).
A better logic is:

to read a char in both files
to compare them and abort if not the same
to loop if end was not reached

That could be written as:
do {
    c1 = fgetc(file1);
    c2 = fgetc(file2);
    if (c1!=c2) {
        // close
        return 0; // different
    }
} while (c1!=EOF); // Here we know that c1==c2
return 1; // Exactly the same

Your code is also wrong in the closing of files:
file1 = fopen(filename1, "r");
file2 = fopen(filename2, "r");

if (file1 == NULL || file2 == NULL) {
    printf("Error occured while reading files.\n");
    fclose(file1);
    fclose(file2);
    return -1;
}

as it may try to close file1 if file1 wasn't opened.
It is undefined to call fclose on NULL. A rewriting could be:
file1 = fopen(filename1, "r");
if (file1==NULL) { return -1; }
file2 = fopen(filename2, "r");
if (file2==NULL) { fclose(file1); return -1; }

